# Debugging wxpython on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, wxpython

I am trying to find out how can I debug a wxpython project in Eclipse. Do I need to install a external debugger (which one?) or can I do this with the Eclipse build-in debugger?

Answer (score 4):

Install the [PyDev extension](http://www.pydev.org/). I love debugging through it :D